# How to call a feature inside another feature in cucumber-jvm?

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a feature file

```
Feature: Create Profile

Scenario: Create Profile
Given I want to create a profile
When I create a profile
Then I should be navigated to Home Page
Then sign out link should exist
```

So the above runs all ok and asserts that it's indeed back in the Home Page and the sign out link exists.

And now I have another feature file.

```
Feature: Go to my account page

Scenario: Go to my account page
Given I want to go to my account page    
When I go to my account page
Then I should be navigated to the my account page
```

Before running `"When I go to my account page"` step, the user should `"Create Profile"`.

So what I did was I appended the

```
When I create a profile
Then I should be navigated to Home Page
Then sign out link should exist
```

before `When I go to my account page`.

But I see that I have duplicated the same code that is in the "Create Profile" feature/scenario.

How do I run the entire "Create Profile" feature/scenario inside the "Go to my account page" scenario?

I am using cucumber-jvm with Selenium and JUnit.

Comment: You might need to create a method called `createOrVerifyProfile` which would intern call all the methods associated with the feature `CreateProfile` or feature `VerifyProfile`

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the Background DSL-feature? It would work for your case but is probably not what you're literally asking about. In this case you can require user to create profile by:

```
Feature: Create Profile
  Background:
    Given I create a profile
    And I should be navigated to Home Page
    And sign out link should exist

  Scenario: Create Profile
    # do nothing because all actions are in background

  Scenario: Go to my account page
    When I go to my account page
    Then I should be navigated to the my account page
```

But you have to merge the two your feature files into a single feature file.

Also take a look at @Before and @After cucumber annotations - so that you can run some code to initialize (or create) an account for your test if previous solution wouldn't work for you.

Comment: is it possible to link to a separate feature file in 'Background:'. That would be perfect. '@Before' and '@After' can not run feature files either i presume.

Answer (score 1):

The `Create Profile` feature specifies the Given/When/Then, because that's what is driving the feature implementation.

Many other features will require the existence of a valid profile. You should not create the profiles for these features by repeating the specification from `Create Profile`. Instead, include something along the lines of `Given I have a valid profile` (maybe in the Background section) and wire that through to fixture code that creates a profile.